# Посчитать количество символов разрешенных по регулярке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как определить какое количество символов разрешено использовать (длину алфавита) например по такой регулярке `A-Za-z0-9_~` ?

Comment: это типа 26+26+10+2 ?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь здесь не определена длина

Comment: интересно как вы будете считать количество для `.*`

Comment: @teran И вообще не понятно зачем нужно это считывать?

Comment: @ Rostyslav Kuzmovych вопрос про регулярные выражения в js. 
@teran да. Вопрос в частности про наборы/диапазоны (все что может быть заключено в [])

Answer (score 0):

Выражение `A-Za-z0-9_~` вернет только

> A-Za-z0-9_~

если это предполагается для input для этого есть атрибуты,например maxlength.
Если вы хотели для `A-Za-z0-9_`,то короче записывается так `[\w]{1,}` или `[\w]+`.Остальное можно посмотреть [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-digit)